# JQuery Emoji picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji

I wanted my users to be allowed to insert emojis into a text box. I have searched for a JQuery plugin, which would allow me to give them a picker like the Mac, iOS or Webogram integrated Emojipicker. But I couldn't find a proper one, which sorted all icons and displayed them?

Is there any possibility to do this?

Mac Emojipicker:

[image]

Comment: come on people upvote this question for god's sake! It's helpful and interesting at the same time

Comment: The SO dogmatism at its best! Great job close voters!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

After the first time I asked this question, I only got down votes. So I thought, probably there isn't any other plugin out there and I developed my own based on [Emojiarea](https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea) (which also Webogram uses). Because I didn't copy the code from Webogram, I didn't sort the icons yet but my solution works how I excepted it.

The custom plugin can be found on my Github Account https://github.com/GittiHab/jquery-emojiarea.

I hope this helps others with a similar problem and takes away some work.

Comment: So glad you didn't get bogged down by the bullies and came up with this answer! SO community needs more people like you!

Comment: Very thankful for this man really appreciable  :)

Comment: emojionearea is much better, http://mervick.github.io/emojionearea

Comment: plus 1 nice work :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your work @JSHelp.

I've found another one here:
https://github.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker

Example usage:

> Initialize the jQuery Emoji Picker by calling emojiPicker on an input element (...):

```
$('.question').emojiPicker({
  height: '300px',
  width: '450px'
});
```

Comment: It's a newer plugin from March 24. 2015. But thank you.

Comment: The picker seems to work, however the emojis displayed inside the textarea are not the colored pictures, but the black symbols instead. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: It not works on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

I've found another one i.e angular-emoji-popup plugins that you can encode and decode emoticons and pick emoji from popup.
This plugins helpful for those who want to show emoji on webpage.
you can download this plugins from github:-
https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup

Comment: This answer is bordering on being "link-only answer" - example of usage is always appreciated. :)

Comment: @bardzusny it's the question that's borderline close-worthy, IMO :-)

Comment: @bardzusny Would you like an example? I can add one for you

Comment: This by the way is also a newer solution from December 2014 (just to keep track)